# My google maps pan zoom control buttons not appearing

Tags: php, google-maps

I have implemented google map in my project . I've set all the required things . I was wondering the control icons not appearing like pan,zoom etc. But still I can zoom ,pan with clicking on a blurred shape instead of the picture buttons . Anybody can address the issue ? .Sorry for my bad english

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=key"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        var latlng = new GLatLng(<?php echo $lattitude?>, <?php echo $longitude?>);
        map.setCenter(latlng, 13);


        var iconRed = new GIcon(); 
        iconRed.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
        iconRed.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
        iconRed.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
        iconRed.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
        iconRed.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
        iconRed.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);





          map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
          map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
          map.addOverlay(new GMarker(latlng));

          var name = "name";
          var address = "address";
          var type = "bar";
          var point = latlng;
          var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, iconRed);
          map.addOverlay(marker);

      }
    }
    function createMarker(point, name, address, iconRed) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, iconRed);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }
```

Comment: yes, please post your code.. also which version of the API and which implementation.. js, php?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful too

Comment: @Mike I've pasted the code . I am using js API

Comment: Not an answer, simply a comment.. why aren't you using v3 of the API. I cant see anything wrong with that code without seeing it in action. Only thing i could suggest is to troubleshoot it by removing all the extra stuff. Define a single marker, with no custom icons or html.

Comment: Can you check this link! http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/

Comment: You should use version 3 of the Google Maps API, http://code.google.com/apis/maps. Version 2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using V2 of the Google Maps API for your app. That version of the API has been deprecated.

Instead you shoule be using V3:

http://goo.gl/YVKfp

Comment: Anyway I changed v to 3 .Now it seems working fine. Thanks all